# jplayer will work only in chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, opera, jplayer

To begin with sorry for possibly obvious question, I looked up some questions, but it didn't seem like someone had similar problem. I'm trying to play a stream through jplayer, but it seems like it's working only in chrome, i suppose there could be problem with stream link, because in IE and Firefox it opens as download, while in opera and chrome starts just playing, but then why my jplayer wont play in opera too. My code  below: and please keep answers simple if possible, because this is kinda new to me:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title> i-radio  SWH Rock</title>
      <link type="text/css" href="jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
              $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "http://80.232.162.149:8000/rock96mp3"
              });
            },
        swfPath: "/js",
            supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window"
          });
         });
      </script>
     </head>
    <body>
       <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
       <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
       <div class="jp-type-single">
  <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
    <ul class="jp-controls">
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="jp-progress">
      <div class="jp-seek-bar">
        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-volume-bar">
      <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-time-holder">
      <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
      <div class="jp-duration"></div>
      <ul class="jp-toggles">
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-title">
            <ul>
              <li>SWH Rock</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
    To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I had a problem with jplayer in IE. I had to update the Adobe Flash player on IE to make it work. Try installing/updating the Flash Player, restart the browser and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: ok found a problem, i forgot to create the folder for swfpath file, bit silly. now everything works fine